# By using integral, how can I find the area of the region $B - A$ when $A$ and $B$ are circles?

Tags: integration, geometry

[image]

By using integral, how can I find the area of the region $B - A$ when $A$ and $B$ are circles?

$B$ and $A$ are circles to have same range L.

Center location of $B$ is (0,0) and that of $A$ is random values (x,y) within L from B's center.

d = $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}  \leq$  L

Comment: It is clear that the result only depends on $L$ and $d$. I would carry over the computation in polar coordinates choosing the center of B as the pole and the polar axis through both centers. The equation of the circle A would be trivial and that of B is easy to find, as well as the limits for the polar angle in terms of d and L. Seems doable, with a bit of patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind, the easiest way to set up the integral is to rotate coordinates so that the center of circle $A$ is at $(d,0)$ while the center of circle $B$ remains at $(0,0)$. Then move the origin of coordinates right by $d/2$ so now circle $B$ is centered at $(-d/2,0)$. Its equation is now
$$\left(x+\frac d2\right)^2+y^2=x^2+y^2+dx+\frac{d^2}4=r^2+dr\cos\theta+\frac{d^2}4=L^2$$
Then along the circle
$$r=-\frac d2\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{\frac{d^2}4\cos^2\theta-\frac{d^2}4+L^2}=-\frac d2\cos\theta+\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}$$
Where we have taken the $(+)$ sign because $r>0$ even when $\theta=\pi/2$. Circle $A$ is centered at $(d/2,0)$ so its equation is
$$\left(x-\frac d2\right)^2+y^2=x^2+y^2-dx+\frac{d^2}4=r^2-dr\cos\theta+\frac{d^2}4=L^2$$
So along this circle,
$$r=\frac d2\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{\frac{d^2}4\cos^2\theta-\frac{d^2}4+L^2}=\frac d2\cos\theta+\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}$$
These cross when
$$-\frac d2\cos\theta+\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}=\frac d2\cos\theta+\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}$$
So $\cos\theta=0$ and $\theta\in\{-\pi/2,\pi/2\}$
Then the area is
$$\begin{align}\Delta&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{-\frac d2\cos\theta+\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}}^{\frac d2\cos\theta+\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}}r\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac12\left[\left(\frac d2\cos\theta+\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}\right)^2-\left(-\frac d2\cos\theta+\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}\right)^2\right]d\theta\\
&=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2}2\left(\frac d2\cos\theta\right)\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta\end{align}$$
If we let $\frac d2\sin\theta=L\sin\phi$ then
$$\begin{align}\int2\left(\frac d2\cos\theta\right)\sqrt{L^2-\frac{d^2}4\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta&=\int2\left(L\cos\phi\right)^2d\phi=L^2\int\left(1+\cos2\phi\right)d\phi\\
&=L^2\left(\phi+\frac12\sin2\phi\right)+C=L^2\left(\phi+\sin\phi\cos\phi\right)+C\\
&=L^2\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac d{2L}\sin\theta\right)+\left(\frac d{2L}\sin\theta\right)\sqrt{1-\frac{d^2}{4L^2}\sin^2\theta}\right)+C\end{align}$$
So the area
$$\begin{align}\Delta&=\left[L^2\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac d{2L}\sin\theta\right)+\left(\frac d{2L}\sin\theta\right)\sqrt{1-\frac{d^2}{4L^2}\sin^2\theta}\right)\right]_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\\
&=2L^2\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac d{2L}\right)+\left(\frac d{2L}\right)\sqrt{1-\frac{d^2}{4L^2}}\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Cut the intersection of the two disks in 4 parts of equal area. With the help of a rotation centered on the middle of the two centers, one obtains that the area of the intersection is equal to
\begin{equation}
4 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{L^2-(d/2)^2}} \left(\sqrt{L^2-u^2} - (d/2)\right) d u
\end{equation}
This can be computed with a substitution $u = L\cos\theta$.